# get label address of assembly using C

Tags: c, assembly

I want to get the label address of assembly in C language. Here is the example

I have a start.S file:

```
.fun:
    // do something
```

And I have a main.c file:

```
volatile unsigned int * p = (unsigned int *) 0x1000;
```

I want to write the label address of 'fun' into the memory of 0x1000, So I write

```
*p = fun;
```

But it cannot be compiled with error info:

```
'fun' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rename `.fun` to `fun` and use `.globl fun` in the assembly file to export the symbol? If the target is Windows and you aren't using ELF then you may have to prepend an `_` (underscore) to the label `fun` in the `.S` file.

Comment: Of course in _C_ you'd also have to declare an `extern` for `fun`

Comment: @MichaelPetch the `_` will have to be prepended if the target is 32 bit. 64 bit name mangling doesn't use `_` at least on Windows.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I may have assumed 32-bit given that is the size implied by his `*p = fun;` and the definition of `p`. (I prefer `uintptr_t` though)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah! Missed that. This makes sense.

Comment: @MichaelPetch What is the type of label? I tried extern unsigned int fun; and *p = fun, it compiles but not working correctly; I can use *p = 0x111, it works, but I want to use the label.

Comment: I don't know how you are using it. Do you intend to call the function? At the basic level you could just do `extern fun;` and take the address of it using `&fun` . If you intend to call `fun` from _C_ then you'll need a proper definition (I can't say what that would be since I don't know anything about the code at label `fun`)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks very much. It works. extern fun; *p = (unsigned int) &fun. I am totally new to assembly and I do think assembly is very wired: no type for 'fun', and using & to get the label address (previously I thought label itself is the number).

Comment: If you had defined it this way `extern void fun(void);` then `fun` would be a function, and you'd access its address as `*p = (unsigned int)fun;`

Answer (score 0):

extern fun;

*p = (unsigned int) &fun;